# When is onQueryTerminated triggered in Apache Spark StreamingQueryListeners?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm developing a custom StreamingQueryListener and I'd like to trigger its onQueryTerminated method in a test.

This is what I tried implementing:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ SQLContext, SparkSession }
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemoryStream
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ col, to_date }
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec

class MyListener extends StreamingQueryListener {
  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit       = {}
  override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit     = {}
  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = println(event.exception)
}

class ListenerSpec extends AnyFlatSpec {

  it should "trigger onQueryTerminated" in {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    spark.streams.addListener(new MyListener())
    implicit val sqlContext: SQLContext = spark.sqlContext

    import spark.implicits._

    val stream = MemoryStream[Int]
    stream.addData(Seq(1, 3, 4))

    val query = stream
      .toDF()
      .withColumn("columnDoesntExist", to_date(col("names")))
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because it raises an AnalysisException but the onQueryTerminated method isn't triggered by the termination of the streaming query.

In what situations is that method triggered and event.exception is Some(exception)?

### Update

The following code successfully triggers the execution of `onQueryTerminated`:

```
val exceptionUdf = udf(() => throw new Exception())

val query = stream
      .toDF()
      .withColumn("exception", exceptionUdf())
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
```

Refer to the accepted answer for an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the book "Stream Processing with Apache Spark" (published by O'Reilly) the `onQueryTerminated` method gets

> "**Called when a streaming query is stopped.** The `event` contains `id` and `runId` fields that correlate with the start event. It also provides an `exception` field that contains an `exception` if the query failed due to an error."

As you are getting an `AnalysisException`, your query did not even start yet. It only got to the first of the four phases in the Catalyst optimizer, which is the "Analysis" and it has not been transformed into runnable code yet:

[image]

More details on the [Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html).

The AnalysisException just means that there are issues in the code related to the Catalog which is exactly what you intended to do: Refer to a column that does not exist (in the Catalog).

If you want to run the execution of the `onQueryTermination` method you need to implement a working code but have it failed while it is already running (e.g. provide wrong data input type).